# MySQL query - show data based on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show cash flow based on what we spent in the company.

We are selling various products day by day, and I have to show transactions in a better way.

Let's say that there is a data like this.

```
Date            Product        Profit
2012-08-17      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-17      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-17      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-16      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-16      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-14      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-13      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-13      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-13      Apple          $1.00
```

We sold 3 apples on Aug 17, and 2 apples on Aug 16.
The one that I am trying to make a query helps to show below result.

```
Date            Product        Total Profit
2012-08-17      Apples         $3.00
2012-08-16      Apple          $2.00
2012-08-14      Apple          $1.00
2012-08-13      Apple          $3.00
```

I need to sum up all profit day by day.

Can you help me to make a query? I failed couple of times. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select date,product,sum(profit) as totalprofit from table
 group by date,product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date,product,SUM(profit) FROM table
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that the product is the same you can use this query:

```
SELECT Date, Product, sum(Profit) as TotalProfit
FROM transactions
GROUP BY Date
```

In the case that the product is not the same you can use this query:

```
SELECT Date, Product, sum(Profit) as TotalProfit
FROM transactions
GROUP BY Product, Date
```